# jQuery addClass on loading window not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I can't get this code working in IE (11), what am I doing wrong here?
Do I need to set a TimeOut?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // Smooth load body content
 $(window).on('load',function() {
   $('body').addClass('loaded');
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease; /* Safari */
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
body.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why wrap window.onload in document.ready handler?

Comment: It's possible the load event has already fired before the `.on("load")` handler is configured (as implied by @raina77ow).   Remove the `.on(load)` part:  `$(function() { $("body").addClass("loaded"); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener which should then work across browser. (Tested IE11 and Chrome).

```
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    loadPage();
 } else {
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
        if(document.readyState === 'complete')
            loadPage();
            }
    )};

function loadPage(){
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
}
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sr9anqez/1/)